# Using ntfs-3g, how to parse Windows extended attributes automatically?

Tags: scripting, ntfs, ntfs-3g, xattr

Using xattrs, one can access Windows extended attributes using the following command

```
getfattr -h -n system.ntfs_ea Ntfs_Mount_Point/some_file
```

The problem is instead of an attribute list, it returns a raw single binary value encoded as base64 or hex containing all the underlying attributes. For example

```
0x1400000000060400244c584d4f4400a411000000
```

I know how to get a parsed result using ntfsinfo, but it requires the volume to be unmounted and I m looking for a file copy based on xattr data which means I need the volume to be mounted.

So for example (since I know the attitude name I m needing), how to get the value of `$LXATTRB` from `Ntfs_Mount_Point/some_file`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you included the output it gives.

But in the meantime, maybe [this](https://github.com/harshavardhana/attrz/blob/master/getfattr.py) code will help you out.

Perhaps this function specifically:

```
line 46: def print_getfattr
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, after your edit, best I could find is a nudge in the right direction:

[This](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntfs-3g-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01672.html) page contains the example you supplied, and another one with some more EA records.

and in [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/cifs-protocol@lists.samba.org/msg00892.html) page, you can see it parsed, all the way in the bottom.
I'm not sure it is parsed *"enough"*, as I could not find out what file mode "a4 11 00 00" is. But as you can see it comes directly after the attribute name, which is in ascii (separated with a null byte).  The EA's length is also there, I think, 0x04 in all of these specifically here. not sure about the 0x06 though.

[image: hexdump1]

Seems to be the case with multiple other extended records as well.

[image: hexdump2]

[This](https://github.com/jschicht/LogFileParser) mentions [EA Tools](https://github.com/jschicht/EaTools/blob/master/EaQuery.au3), which may also come in handy, and also gives [references](https://github.com/jschicht/EaTools) to msdn in "Technical details"

Maybe try comparing the output from ntfsinfo to the hex dump shown, see if anything pops out.

Good luck in your NTFS journey.

Comment: Wrong answer! From a Linux side, all Windows extended attributes are stored in the $EA extended attributes. getfattr only allows to get `$EA` containing all attributes and the question is how to parse it.

Comment: I see. Can you give an example of the $EA "blob" you get? the code I linked also contains parsing, inside the function.

Comment: I m not interested in manual parsing, but in automatic parsing as I ve 2 millions files to update from `$LXATTRB`. Even then, the format is more difficult to understand as some values are bytes or 16 bits aligned. **What gave in tooling is using the Windows api, which can t be used to write `$EA`**